# Get the state of a class from anywhere like global variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `Parent` class which has `MainDiv` and `LoadngPopper`.

In this case I want to get `MainDiv` state from `LoadingPopper`

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <MainDiv>
      <LoadingPopper>
    )
  }
}

class MainDiv extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      loading:0
    }
  }
}
class LoadingPopper extends React.Component{
  render(){
    //want to check MainDiv.state.loading here
    return();
  }
}
```

I can find how to give the parameter to parent to child or vice verse.

So, I can give the state from `MainDiv -> Parent -> LoadingPopper`

However in this case, I want to quickly access to `MainDiv` from anywhere like global variables.

Is it possible get the `MainDiv` instance directly from `LoadingPopper`?

Comment: possible but not a good idea, instead you can choose Redux or React Context which is designed for this purpose

Comment: I choose to use `React Context`. thank you very much.

Comment: Unless you have a huge and complicated component tree, you shouldn't use Redux or React context. https://blog.logrocket.com/pitfalls-of-overusing-react-context/

Answer (score 0):

Managing states inside a parent component allows accessing the states among its child components. (MainDiv and LoadingPopper)

Please check the official React documentation for more information:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Unless you have a huge and complicated component tree, I recommend simply sharing states from a parent component instead of using a state management library such as Redux to achieve this.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
          loading:0
      }
      this.toggleLoading = this.toggleLoading.bind(this);
  }

  toggleLoading() {
      if(this.state === 0) {
          this.setState({ loading: 1 });
          return ;
      }
      this.setState({ loading: 0 });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <MainDiv loading={this.state.loading} toggleLoading={this.toggleLoading} />
      <LoadingPopper loading={this.state.loading} />
    )
  }
}

class MainDiv extends React.Component{
      //set loading state here by using this.props.toggleLoading
  }
}

class LoadingPopper extends React.Component{
      //check loading state here
}
```